# How to check whether our Send TO short id is valid from addressbook

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

```
    doc.Principal = confdoc.mDefaultPrincipal(0)
    doc.SendTo = curdoc.empShortID(0)

    Call doc.Send(False, False)
```

Above Call doc.Send(False, False) is not going to error handler though doc.SendTo has wrong short id since it has CC and BCC short ids are correct. My requirement is it should go to error handler or it should not send mail when send to is wrong. How can i check send to from address book.

```
 errorhandler:
Print "Error in function TriggerMail -- " & Cstr(Error) &  " -- occured at line - " & Cstr(Erl())   
MsgBox Err

If Err = 4294 Then
    curdoc.Flag = "Invalid 'To' Shortname"
    curdoc.defaulterSLACount = CInt(defaultCount)
    Call curdoc.Save(False, True)
    Exit function
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately this will not generate an error as long as at least ONE address is OK. 
You have to check all adresses manually to get an error. Best way is to go through all addresses, and look them up in ($Users)- View in domino directory.
This might look like this:

```
Dim varRecipients as Variant
varRecipients = doc.SendTo
varRecipients = ArrayUnique( ArrayAppend( varRecipients, doc.CopyTo ) )
varRecipients = ArrayUnique( ArrayAppend( varRecipients, doc.BlindCopyTo ) )

Dim dbNab as NotesDatabase
Dim viwLkp as NotesView
Dim docPerson as NotesDocument
Set dbNab = New NotesDatabase( db.Server, "names.nsf" )
Set viwLkp = dbNab.GetView( "($Users)" )
Forall strRecipient in varRecipients
  '- this check is optional. Addresses with an @ never create an err 4294
  '- If your function never sends mails outside of the domain, you can omit it.
  If instr( strRecipient, "@" ) = 0 then
    Set docPerson = viwLkp.GetDocumentByKey( strRecipient, True )
    If docPerson is Nothing then
      '- flag your document, do whatever you want, 
      '- as this recipient does not exist
    End If
  End If
End Forall
```

This code is not tested, but the idea should be clear, even if there are typos in this example (no Designer open at the moment to check).

Comment: Going to the $Users view is fine if you know for sure that there is only one Domino Directory configured for the server. The LookupNames method of the NotesDirectory class is preferable, assuming that you're dealing with Notes 8 or above.

Comment: This is right and a good point. But:LookupNames also searches in the local names.nsf of the client... And that might be contraproductive in some cases